# How well does the Macbook Air work with Ubuntu?

Tags: macbook-air

I'm thinking of getting a nice laptop [thin like Macbook Air, Actually I'm thinking of getting Macbook Air itself]. Question is, how well it will go with Ubuntu.

Being ubuntu user for last 7 years, I cant think of moving away just for great hardware capabilities in AirBook. However, It would be great if Ubuntu 11.04 runs on Airbook smoothly without much of messy.

I would wish to have all Ubuntu 11.04 features to work with Macbook Air.[Video/Audio, Keyboard, Touchpad, etc]. Is there users out here tried and would recommend Macbook Air ?. Any good guide would help as well.

Comment: If you buy this laptop in a store, ask them to boot a live cd/usb as a test. :)

Comment: @Daniel. I know, booting live CD/usb wont work. They have so called   superdrive.. What to do, sometime people wont get everything. :). We need to work around and get what we want. !! :)

Comment: Also see [How to install on a Macbook Air without external CD Drive](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10561/how-to-install-on-a-macbook-air-3-2-without-an-external-cd-drive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good discussion on the [Apple Users section of ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1603365) which is definitely worth a read through and contains probably the most up to date guide and experiences which others have had. You could also look at:
http://ebsi4711.blogspot.com/2010/10/ubuntu-on-macbookair31-11.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Ubuntu on a Macbook Air 4,2 (mid 2011), and I'm not sure I'd do it again (buying an Air, despite the nice hardware). Setting up any Linux on an Air is really much hassle, since it cannot boot Linux off an USB stick (mac firmware problems).

If you have an official apple superdrive, using the install CD is supposed to work nice, but without it's too much pain.

---

See http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/ubuntu-on-macbook-air.htm for an installation howto and a hardware support table for Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 1):

Install rEfit. Its a handy boot manager that allows you to boot from a usb thumb drive. MAke your ubuntu installation drive as you can see on the ubuntu download site. AFter that,use bootcamp to partition your drive. Boot from ubuntu installation drive and you're good to go. :D 
It works fine on my macbook Air. :D hope it works for you.