# How to install(not live cd!) Ubuntu on USB flash that will be bootable on mac

Tags: boot, usb, mac

1. I have a mac book pro 13 retina.
2. I have 2 USB flash drives.
3. I've uploaded a live usb image of Ubuntu on the first flash drive and it works.
4. I'm trying to install Ubuntu on the second flash drive from the first flash drive.
5. Installation works fine.
6. After reboot I cannot see the second flash drive in boot menu.

I've tried:

- Install 1 partition ext4 and select it as a boot partition. It does not see a flash drive.
- Install 2 partition, first "efi" and second ext4 for /. It sees the second flash drive, but when I'm trying to boot - it says "Isolinux.bin missing or corrupt"

I really need an Ubuntu physical machine, But I do not want to install it on my hard drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu USB on a Mac](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67221/ubuntu-usb-on-a-mac)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/401273/how-do-you-create-a-live-persistent-ubuntu-usb-on-a-mac-that-will-boot-to-a-mac

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this on a friend's mid 2011 iMac.

What I did was burn rEFInd onto a CD, and then, when I wanted to boot from the Ubuntu USB drive, I would first boot to the CD, and then from the CD's menu boot Ubuntu.

You can get rEFInd [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/).

If you don't want to use a CD to boot the USB drive, I suggest you give this page a read. http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html

Comment: the OP dont wont use CDs but explicit an USB drive.

Comment: @cmks - Updated answer